# Adding item names and corresponding mean values to print message in R

Tags: r, mean

I have a data-frame `newdat1`of which I am obtaining item (column) means as follows:

```
means<-sapply(newdat1,mean)
> print(means)
      i3       i2       i1 
1.290640 1.330049 1.231527
```

I am trying to obtain a print message that gives the item names and the corresponding mean values as follows:
`"i3 1.29064039408867, i2 1.33004926108374, i1 1.23152709359606 are the means in this analysis"`
However, all I am able to obtain is:

```
> sprintf("%s are the means in this analysis", paste(means, collapse = ", "))
[1] "1.29064039408867, 1.33004926108374, 1.23152709359606 are the means in this analysis"
```

So basically I am trying to add the item names to the print message.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using the `names`, it will not print it.  So, we add that in the `paste` step and it should print as expected.

```
 sprintf("%s are the means in this analysis",
            paste(names(means), means, collapse = ", "))
 #[1] "i3 1.29064, i2 1.330049, i1 1.231527 are the means in this analysis"
```